# Include an enum from within a class, without including the in SWIG

Tags: c++, enums, swig

Some of the interfaces i have to map with SWIG are using interfaces from classes i other libraries. 
For example i have a parameter of type `const boost::asio::ssl::context::file_format` which is refering to an enum defined as:

```
// ssl/context_base.hpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
// [...]

namespace boost {
namespace asio {
namespace ssl {

class context_base
{
public:
  // [...]

  /// File format types.
  enum file_format
  {
    /// ASN.1 file.
    asn1,

    /// PEM file.
    pem
  };
};

} } }
```

If i `%include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>` then all the methods are going to be generated and give me a lot of different errors.

If i just copy the whole definition from above to the `.i` file and (in this case) boost does extend the enum, i would have to remember to change the interface file accordingly.

I would prefer to be able to include only the enum from the boost header files, but i can't find a way to do that. There are only functions to ignore methods/classes, but none to select them.

Is there any way to get the enum generated based on the header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i did find a solution, which is using %rename to ignore all members of the class except enums and enumitems.

```
%rename("$ignore", "not" %$isenum, "not" %$isenumitem, regextarget=1, fullname=1) "^boost::asio::ssl::context_base::"; 
%include <boost/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp>
```

This is not perfect, as it does ignore everything starting with `boost::asio::ssl::context_base::`. But it does solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use preprocessor :

```
#ifndef SWIG
//what you don't want in swig
#endif
```

Comment: unfortunately i can't modify the systems boost library headers, so this won't help